# send hbase data (mp3 files) to webservice

Tags: java, rest, hbase

I want to send the hbase data which is mp3 file to the REST webservice.  I am getting the data from aws and storing it into hbase table and want to expose this data to the webservice once i call the webservice by putting some parameter.

Comment: Since you already use aws, why don't you store them in S3 bucket and save only s3 links to hbase table ?  Hbase can store files but it is not designed as a file storage.

Comment: Hi halil,i do now want to share aws user credentials with anyone. as only link would not suffice if someone want to download mp3 files.

Comment: You can make your bucket public accessible for these mp3 files. You did not have to share access key with users.

Comment: halil, i am not the owner of the bucket but just using it. and have only access to mp3 files. m trying to code it in rest webservice.  if you have any idea about the webservice code please do let me know.. thanks for your prompt replies...